# How do i add a column of totals only if the "Name" variable is the same

Tags: pandas, dataframe, cumulative-sum, inventory, subtotal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMFiu.png)

I am trying to keep track of inventory and we use the Frebreeze for example,

There are 2 cases of 6 so 12 sub total.

Lets say we buy 2 of those, and there are two separate data point.

I want a column with 24 total.

I want to add the Total tab to make a Inventory tab based upon Name.

Another example

We buy two six packs of Diet Coke, I want the program to say if the df["UPC"] are the same, then add the "subTotal" column to make an "Total" Column with the accumulated Totals based upon name.

I want to be able to look at Diet and say "Ok we bought a six pack, but total we have 24 cans of soda "

Havent tried anything to be honest, I feel like theres a way to make a if and statement for this but I just can't put my finger on it

Comment: post the sample dataframe as text so it can be copied and reproduced.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your request, you need a summation based on `UPC` column.

If so:

```py
df['Total_by_UPC'] = df.groupby('UPC').agg({'subTotal' : 'sum'})
```

Another option: cumulative sum of `subTotal` column based on UPC.

```py
df['CumulativeSum_by_UPC'] = df.groupby('UPC').agg({'subTotal' : 'cumsum'})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked but unexpectedly stopped working out of no where. But this was definitely a step in the right direction, and was definitely helpful. Thank you for taking the time :')

Comment: This operation may be costly for your hardware, or your dataset may be too large. I'd recommend splitting your data into small chunks, for example `df_small = df.iloc[:100, :]` this could result in creating `df_small` with the first 100 rows of your data -- to make sure that code behaves the way you'd expect